# Phonegap - build fails after including my js files

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to build a Phonegap app, but get an error when running:

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" phonegap build android

Error Code: 1
Unable to add '.../app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/react-backbone/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/node-notifier/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz': file already in archive (try '-u'?)
ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging '.../app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_'
```

A brand new project builds fine. The moment I add my own css and js files and modify the index view, it fails. Even after commenting out the external css and js files I'm loading, it fails.

Could the very inclusion of a foreign directory in `www/` confuse Phonegap and cause this error?

**Edit:**

Differences between working app and the broken one.

[image]

My new `index.html`:

Replaced

```
<div class="app">
  <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
  <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
    <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
    <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="app"></div>
```

There are some css/js imports, but I commented them out, so they shouldn't be affecting anything.

Inside the new directory I have:

[image]

I'll try creating a completely new app and only adding this directory to see if that messes it up.
Will update.

**Update:**
I just confirmed that adding that directory causes a problem with the build process. Maybe I'm supposed to put it somewhere else?

**Update 2:**
I fixed the issue, but I don't understand what the problem was, so I would still like a response if anyone knows.

I created another project and reorganized the code. I stuck some of the files from the new directory in `js/`, some in `css/`, etc. I created a `build` directory as well and that didn't cause any issues.

Comment: Provide a fullstack of your folder tree before import and after import, that would be great.

Comment: Should I just diff it, or would it be helpful to see the original directory tree (which is the default one after creating a project)?

Comment: The default one isn't needed, sorry. Only files you copy, and to which directory you copy them. Screenshots would be very helpfull.